# What is wc -c different from ${#} when I count number of characters in Linux?

Tags: bash, wc

```
echo $SHELL
/bin/bash

echo $SHELL | wc -c
10

echo ${#SHELL}
9
```

The number of characters in `$SHELL` (e.g. `/bin/bash`) is 9, so why is the result is 10 when use `wc -c`?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate question, but there is a nuance to this question that the other one does not have.

Comment: @BenWhaley But answer can't possibly add anything new

Comment: Actually it can, and I'm about to demonstrate that in a comment since the question is closed.

Comment: The nuance is that `${#SHELL}` is a [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html). The expansion performs the character count without the newline since `echo` hasn't actually run yet. So `echo ${#SHELL}` actually translates to `echo 9` with a trailing newline.

Comment: @BenWhaley Agreed. The Q is much better than the linked one. Feel free to add the answer

Comment: :) Thanks @Inian!

Comment: Perhaps also worth understanding why the output of `foo='a       b          c'; echo $foo | wc -c; echo ${#foo};`  is 6 and 20.

Comment: try `echo -n $SHELL | wc -c`, it'll result in 9

Comment: @disney82231 : You can find this out by replacing `wc -c` by `xxd`....

Answer (score 5):

It's because of the newline added by `echo`. When you type:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$
```

`echo` prints a newline character, which is counted in the `wc` character count.

On the other hand, `${#SHELL}` is a [shell expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html). The shell performs the character count using an expansion without the extra newline character since `echo` hasn't actually run yet. So `echo ${#SHELL}` actually translates to `echo 9`. The `9` is printed with a trailing new line added by `echo`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm strongly recommend to use shell expansion. Here `${#SHELL}`

Warning with `wc -c` that count BYTES. Not characters.

If you want to count characters with it, use `wc -m`

It's very important when you not only use ASCII chars table and an UTF-8 terminal (or whatever multibytes charset) or in I18N context

Try this:

```sh
$ x="/x/♤/é/"
$ echo ${#x}
$ echo -n "$x" | wc -c
$ echo -n "$x" | wc -m
```